# Proving two propositions are logically equivalent (without truth table)

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, equivalence

I have to prove that `~p→(q→r)≡ q→(pvr)`

This is what I've done so far:

```
q→(pvr)

≡(q→p)v(q→r)

≡ ~(q→p)→(q→r)

≡ (q^~p)→(q→r)

≡ q→(~qvr) v ~p→(q→r)

≡ ~qv(~qvr) v ~p→(q→r)

≡ (~qvr)v ~p→(q→r)

≡ (q→r) v [~p→(q→r)]
```

How should i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~p→(q→r) <=> p v (q→r) <=> p v (~q v r) <=> p v ~q v r
q→(p v r) <=> ~q v (p v r) <=> ~q v p v r <=> p v ~q v r
```

Here I am using the rule that `p→q <=> ~p v q` and the fact that disjunction is associative and commutative.

Comment: Thanks man! Guess i should have tried solving it the other way around.